# What are the best explanations for d-structure and s-structure in sentences?

Tags: syntax

What are the best explanations to present the ideas of d-structure and s-structure in sentences?

Comment: For those of us who don't believe there is a difference between d-structure and s-structure, there are no good explanations.

Comment: See also https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/27127/why-is-there-no-d-structure-or-s-structure-within-minimalism